# Android: Image gallery share to app

Tags: android, image, gallery, share

I've got an app that accepts images from the image gallery (via share menu). My app starts, and I do this:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    Object obj = bundle.get("android.intent.extra.STREAM");
```

While debugging, Eclipse is reporting the object obj is of type 'Uri@StringUri' (???) and inside it somewhere is the string 'content://media/external/images/media/992'. Anybody know what type of object obj is so I can typecast it? And what's the string about? IE, how do I get to the image data?

Answer (score 2):

It is of type `Uri`, a Universal Resource Identifier.

`content://media/external/images/media/992` is the URI of the image. To turn it into a direct file system path, pass the URI to this method which I found elsewhere on this site:

```
// Convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery( contentUri,
            proj, // Which columns to return
            null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
```